# The nth integral of $\frac{1}{1-x}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was taking the nth integral of both sides of the geometric series sum formula with the first term being 1:

$$I^n \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{r=n}^\infty \frac{r!x^{r+n}}{(r+n)!} + P$$

Wher $P$ is some polynomial. I literally just got the nth integral of $\frac{1}{1-x}$, but I am sure that there’s another way without using an infinite series. In another post I saw that the nth integral of $\frac{1}{x} $ is $$\frac{x^{n-1}\ln x}{\Gamma (n)}+ P$$ Could I just plug in $1-x$ for $x$ and be done? I feel skeptical about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take it as given that $I^n\left[\frac{1}{x}\right] = \frac{x^{n-1} \ln x}{\Gamma(n)} + P_n$, where $P_n$ is a degree $n-1$ polynomial, then we *can't* just substitute $1-x$ for $x$ and call it a day, but we can use that to make things much easier. Set $T_n(x) = I^n\left[\frac{1}{x}\right]$, and notice that:

$\begin{eqnarray} \frac{d}{dx} \left( T_n(1 - x) \right)& = & T_n'(1 - x) \frac{d}{dx} (1 - x) \\
& = & -T_{n - 1}(1 - x) \end{eqnarray}$

Since taking the derivative of $T_n$ reverses one of the integrals, taking us back to $T_{n-1}$.

From here, it's pretty quick to derive that $\frac{d^n}{dx^n} T_n(1 - x) = (-1)^n T_0(1 - x) = \frac{1}{1 - x}$, and hence your idea of substituting $1 - x$ was only off by a factor of $(-1)^n$.

Proving that this is equivalent to your expression is left as an exercise for the reader.